# Handling drag-and-drop with a moving list

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

I'm working with drag-and-drop. The user has to drag something from a list to somewhere else. However, the list will move when receiving a `ListSelectionEvent`, so *when the user changes selection, he may unexpectedly perform a drag-and-drop*.

My code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class Main {
    public static void createGUI() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        JList<String> list = new JList<>(new String[] { "Text A", "Text B" });
        list.setFont(list.getFont().deriveFont(24f));
        list.setDragEnabled(true);
        // list.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler() { /* ... */ });
        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        list.addListSelectionListener(e -> f.setLocation(f.getX(),
                f.getY() + f.getHeight()));
        list.setSelectedIndex(0);

        f.add(list, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.pack();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Main::createGUI);
    }
}
```

To reproduce, launch this application, put it above some application that accepts a drop (e.g. Eclipse, Notepad++) and toggle the selection several times.

I'm using Windows 7 and JDK 1.8.0_5.

I tried but I couldn't find a work-around. **How can I fix this issue?**

---

[Not really related] This is my real application: (including the green cross icon)

[image: Screenshot (Empty)] [image: Screenshot (TopCoder)]

Comment: Just end-user thoughts after testing your code: 1) I'd really hate an application that behaves in that way. I mean, what is the point of move the list on a selection event? If I'd use DnD I'd expect components remain quiet so I can visually double check I'm dragging the right list item. 2) Moving the list is prone to unexpected drops as you have noted. 3) I know it's just an example but after doing two selections the frame isn't visible in my screen anymore.

Comment: @dic19 Cheer up! I made an update regarding your first and third point.

Comment: So, you don't want the Drag and Drop effect anywhere or do you want to modify where it drops? (Also, I think I've found the weirdest corner case of DnD usage ever ;).)

Comment: @dudeprgm *when* it drags.

Comment: Just making sure I give the correct answer here: you want to get a notification when the user drags, am I right? (If you want to disable the DnD entirely, just use `list.setTransferHandler(null)`, but I don't think that's what you want.)

Comment: @dudeprgm What notification? I want to prevent DnD when the user is changing selection (a click) instead of dragging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I think I understand your problem: You want to have DnD enabled, just not when the user is changing their selection. You should try this (in Java 7, I'm not too comfortable with lambda expressions yet, so I'm still not using Java 8. It'll work on Java 8 though):

```
class Main {
    private static boolean listChanging = false;

    public static void createGUI() {
        final JFrame f = new JFrame();
        JList<String> list = new JList<String>(new String[] { "Text A", "Text B" });
        list.setFont(list.getFont().deriveFont(24f));
        list.setDragEnabled(true);
        list.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
                if (listChanging) {
                    listChanging = false;
                    return NONE;
                } else {
                    return COPY;
                }
            }

            @Override
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            public Transferable createTransferable(JComponent c) {
                return new StringSelection(((JList<String>) c).getSelectedValue());
            }
        });
        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                f.setLocation(f.getX(), f.getY() + f.getHeight());
                listChanging = true;
            }
        });
        list.setSelectedIndex(0);
        f.add(list, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.pack();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Main.createGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What this code does is that when the user when the user changes selection it set a variable `listChanging` to `true`. The when the user drags (by accident or on purpose), it checks if `listChanging` is `true`, which means that this was probably an unexpected drag. If the list was not changing, then it allows `COPY` drags.

Basically, if the drag was during a list change, it disables DnD. If the list did not change, and the user purposefully dragged it enables DnD.

Hope this meets all your needs :)

Comment: Looks reasonable. I'll try it when I'm working on the application.

Comment: @johnchen902 Okay, let me know how it works for you and I can update/change it.

Comment: Yes it works! There's a problem that the list doesn't always move, but I've solved it by checking time. If you have better suggestions, I'll be appreciated!

Comment: Of course I will, but I would like to wait until the bounty ends.

Answer (score 0):

Still It's not clear what you want to do with your application..
Drag and Drop performs with mouse/key events or you may trigger it through another events.
Here as I can see, it could be in this way that either you can select some of the components from List and perform DnD to transfer that component to another Container.

Please elaborate your question and ask specifically what exactly you want to perform with your sample application.

Comment: I think my question is clear enough: fix the bug. And please elaborate your answer. In its current state, it should be a comment.